# How to test if url starts with a specific string in JS

Tags: jquery

I tried this, which I feel should have worked having read through a couple previous questions here:

```
$(function(){
    if(/tekstovi.test(window.location.href)) {
        $('#tekst').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

I want the element with ID #tekst to have the active class if the URL contains "/tekstovi"...

Comment: [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a backslash will do the trick, check this:

```js
console.log(/\/tekstovi/.test("/tekstovi"));
```

If you want to check that `window.location.href` starts with `/tekstovi`, use this:

```js
//checks if window.location.href starts with /tekstovi
console.log(/^\/tekstovi/.test("/tekstovi"));

//this will return false
console.log(/^\/tekstovi/.test("foo/tekstovi"));
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. I did however need to convert the URL into a variable. For some reason, it didn't work when passing window.location.href directly into the test() function. I am new to jquery/javascript....

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert your URL into a variable. Then just check if that variable contains the substring you want with the `indexOf()` function.

It would look something like this:

```
var url = window.location.href;
if(url.indexOf('/tekstovi')){
  $('#tekst').addClass('active');
}
```